# Memoize function passes function and returns function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, memoization

I am having multiple problems with this function. It's part of a bonus question for a Data Structures and Algorithms class and I've invested so much time in this one problem, that I'd really like to get it to work and understand what's going on.

There is one main problem, which has caused several little ones...this problem's name is JavaScript. We've never programmed in JavaScript before, but for some reason we have to use it.

The function has to pass tests (this one and fibonacci), which are structured like this:

```
var fn = (n) => 2 * n
var m_fn = memoize(fn)
expect(m_fn(18)).to.equal(fn(18))
```

So I have to pass the function I want to memoize as a parameter of the memoize function and the memoize function has to return a function. I am not allowed to do it any other way.

I did all of the reading and researched the memoize function, but all of the implementations take a different approach.

Basically, I understand what I have to do, but I don't quite understand HOW. I know what the memoize function should do, but I don't understand how to adjust the original function using my memoize function. This is what I have so far/what I don't have:

I know it's wrong. But I think I'm missing something major. I am supposed to return a function, but I am returning values...

In the test, it's writen var m_fn = memoize(fn), so the memoize function passes fn, then returns a new function, but in my memoize, I am returning values for fn(n), so I AM doing something wrong...

```
/**
* Creates a memoized version of the function fn. It is assumed that fn is a referentially transparent
* function.
* @param {function} fn Some referentially transparent function that takes a basic datatype (i.e. number / string)
* @returns {function} A new function that is the memoized version of fn. It never calculates the result of
* a function twice.
*/
memoize: (fn) => { //here we enter the function that we want to memoize
 var memory = []; //we need to create an array to hold the previously calculated values, length n (parameter of fn)

 if(this.n > memory.length){ //Check to see if this particular value is in the array already.  
   return memory[this.n]; //How do I access the integer parameter that was passed through fn though? Is this correct?
 } else{ // if not, we want to save it and return it
   var result = fn(this.n);
   memory.push(result);
   return result;
 }
```

}

Comment: I think the OP used *"the problem's name is JavaScript"* as a hyperbole and is quite aware of the lack of understanding on their side.

Comment: In a code comment you've said *"A new function that is the memoized version of fn. It never calculates the result of a function twice."* so is `m_fn` supposed to cache the results of calling `fn` for a given input value and return the result directly rather than calling it again? What assumptions, if any, can be made about the arguments `fn` (and therefore `m_fn`) will receive?

Comment: Yes, I am quite aware that I know nothing about JavaScript. I have really tried within the last week to grasp the basics, but as I mentioned, we never really had an "introduction to JavaScript"; we were just told to program in it. While that does remain an excuse, it is also a large part of the reason, why I am having difficulty grasping this.

Comment: Could `fn` be another function that needs more than one argument, and/or a non-numerical argument, like an object? Or should we assume `fn` will always be a function that takes one numerical argument?

Comment: The memoize function is a function which is supposed to cut back on the necessity for recursions by saving the previously calculated recursion values in an array or similar data structure. So, if the function calculated the Fibonacci value for 4, when it called the first recursion fib(n-1) or in this ex. 3, it would save the fib values of that recursion (fib(2) and fib(1)), so that when the second recursion was called fib(n-2) or 2 in this example, they wouldn't have to be calculated through recursion, since the values were saved in the array, when we calculated n-1.

Comment: fn always only has one argument in the tests. There are actually only two tests. The one above and the Fibonacci function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you need to return a function.

Secondly, an array is not the ideal structure for `memory`, because it takes linear time to find an argument value in it. I would suggest to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this, which is ideal for such purposes. It has `has()`, `get()` and `set()` methods which run in near-constant time:

```js
function memoize(fn) {
    var memory = new Map();
    return function(arg) {
        if (memory.has(arg)) {
            console.log('using memory');
            return memory.get(arg);
        } else {
            var result = fn(arg);
            memory.set(arg, result);
            return result;
        }
    };
}

var fn = (n) => 2 * n
var m_fn = memoize(fn)

console.log(fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(18)); // outputs also "using memory"
```

Comment: I **just** realized we could use `Map` when adding a comment in my answer saying "I've assumed we can use ES2015 features..." :-)

Comment: We think alike :-)

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This was what I was missing. Just to confirm that I understand correctly. arg corresponds to the parameter n that I am passing through the original function, fn?

Comment: @LisaEver: Yes. When you call `m_fn`, you're calling the function returned by `memoize`, which receives the argument you give it as `arg` and then either returns the stored result or calls `fn` and stores it (and returns the result).

Comment: Indeed, I called it `arg` to silently suggest that it could also be a string (if the memoized function can deal with that) or other primitive(!) value. But it is indeed the *n* you speak of.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as memory.

```js
var memoize = f => 
        (map => v => (!map.has(v) && map.set(v, f(v)), map.get(v)))(new Map),
    fn = (n) => 2 * n,
    m_fn = memoize(fn);

console.log(m_fn(18), fn(18));
```

Comment: Nice and concise as always ;-)

Comment: i changed the parameter to `f`.

Comment: Sorry. What tricked me was `console.log(m_fn(18), fn(18));` which I read as `console.log(m_fn(18), m_fn(18));`. I was going **nuts** trying to figure out why it was calling `fn` more than once for the same value...

Comment: I really like this answer but as @T.J.Crowder just demonstrated, it is not the easiest to follow, especially if OP finds _JavaScript_ a _problem_ :(

Comment: it is a bit golfed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and in-code comments and assuming I'm interpreting correctly, you're really close to the solution. As you've said in the question, you need to return a *function* that returns the values rather than returning the values.

See comments for explanation:

```js
function memoize(f) {
  // An array in which to remember objects with the input arg and result 
  var memory = [];
  
  // This is the function that will use that array; this is the
  // return value of memoize
  return function(arg) {
    // This code runs when the function returned by memoize is called
    // It's *here* that we want to process the argument, check the `memory`
    // array, call `f` if necessary, etc.
    var entry;
    
    // See if we have a previously-saved result for `arg`
    var entry = memory.find(entry => entry.arg === arg);
    if (!entry) {
      // No -- call `fn`, remember the `arg` and result in an object
      // we store in memory``
      entry = {arg, result: f(arg)};
      memory.push(entry);
    }
    
    // We have it (now), return the result
    return entry.result;
  };
}
function fn(arg) {
  console.log("fn called with " + arg);
  return 2 * arg;
}
var m_fn = memoize(fn);
console.log(m_fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(20));
console.log(m_fn(20));
```

Note: There was an arrow function in your code, so I've assumed it's okay to use ES2015 features above. There's not actually very much of it, though, just the arrow function passed to `memory.find`, the assumption that `Array#find` will be available, and the syntax used to create the entry object (in ES5 we' need `entry = {arg: arg, result: f(arg)}` instead).

Note that if we can assume that `arg` will be a string or number or other value that can reliably be converted to string, we can use an object to store the data rather than an array.

And actually, given this is ES2015, we can use a `Map`:

```js
function memoize(f) {
  // An Map in which to remember objects with the input arg and result 
  const memory = new Map();
  
  // This is the function that will use that array; this is the
  // return value of memoize
  return function(arg) {
    // This code runs when the function returned by memoize is called
    // It's *here* that we want to process the argument, check the `memory`
    // array, call `f` if necessary, etc.
    let result;
    
    // See if we have a previously-saved result for `arg`
    if (!memory.has(arg)) {
      // No -- call `fn`, remember the `arg` and result in an object
      // we store in memory``
      result = f(arg);
      memory.set(arg, result);
    } else {
      // Yes, get it
      result = memory.get(arg);
    }
    
    // We have it (now), return the result
    return result;
  };
}
function fn(arg) {
  console.log("fn called with " + arg);
  return 2 * arg;
}
var m_fn = memoize(fn);
console.log(m_fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(18));
console.log(m_fn(20));
console.log(m_fn(20));
```

Note that in both cases, I've written the code verbosely to allow for comments and easy comprehension. The ES2015 version with `Map`, in particular, can be *quite* a lot shorter.

Comment: Thank you! The comments are super helpful. I think I understand what the problem was now. I can return a function and still return values inside of the function that I am returning! That was definitely the point where my brain turned off.

Comment: @LisaEver: Yours and many others' (including mine, when first I encoutered it)! :-) It's one of the really cool things about JavaScript. The concept is that the function we're returning "closes over" the context in which it was created, and that context contains all the variables and such for the call to `memoize`, so the function has access to them. More on my anemic little blog, though the terminology in the article is outdated: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)